# inclusion filter with ruby on rails rspec on travis-ci

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, travis-ci

I'm trying to do integration testing on travis-ci.  I want to be able to run an inclusion filter on travis.  in a gist, I want to be able to run fast tests locally while travis-ci tests the fast tests and slow tests including internet dependent tests.  I have tried using --tag ~slow_tests under .travis.yml but it gives me an error.  here is my .yml file.

```
language: ruby             
rvm:                       
  - 1.9.3                  

env:                       
  - DB=sqlite              

script:                    
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake --trace db:migrate spec --tag ~slow_tests                                                                                                                             

services:                  
  - redis-server
```

invalid option: --tag
129
130The command "RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake --trace db:migrate spec --tag ~slow_tests" exited with 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that the `--tag` option is being interpreted by `rake` which has no such option. So you need a way to pass the command line options through to RSpec. You can do that with the SPEC_OPTS environment variable:

```
script:
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake --trace db:migrate spec SPEC_OPTS="--tag ~slow_tests"
```